# Internationlisation plain Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Assume I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navMenu">
    <li>{{inter.home}}</li>
    <li>{{inter.aboutUs}}</li>
</ul>
```

**express**

```
router.get('/:lang/news', function (req, res) {
var language = req.params.lang;

var interObjects = {
    ru: russianInterObj,
    en: englishInterObj
};

(interObjects[language]) ? res.render('view.hjs', {inter: interObjects[language], ...}) 
                         : res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Would this approach for internationlisation be good?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing it from scratch when there are some great packages available for internationlisation ?

Comment: I don't have major content change for internalisation and I don't want to overload my project with extra packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 points of view on created localized pages :

### External (consumer)

You will have a domain.com/lang/page.html type of URL, which is what is expected. In this regard, your approach is undoubtedly good.

### Internal (provider / developper)

In regard of maintaining code however, while your approach is good, it might be hard to extend it beyond a few lines.

If you are sure your locale data structures won't go beyond a hundred lines at most, I'd advise you to keep this. If you might have to extend it later, you should prefer a more extensible method, probably by using a package designed for this (a quick search on npmjs will return you a few)